# Cannot quote unicode string in Python

Tags: python, unicode, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a unicode object `userId` that contains a non-ascii character. I am trying to quote this string to use it as an XML attribute using a function from xml.sax.saxutils:

```
quoteattr(userId)
```

which gives me this error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0'
```

I think I have read all the python unicode information on the web, including https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type

but I still do not understand what the problem is. I already have a **unicode** object. I don't care about encodings. Encodings are when I want to convert from unicode to byte array or vice versa. Never in my code I am dealing with raw byte arrays.

Basically the big question is why does `quoteattr` want to encode something using ascii encoding if I gave it a **unicode** object and expect **unicode** object back?

I worked around the problem by doing `userId.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`, but this obviously throws away any non-ascii characters.

How can I get my unicode string quoted?

The variable is assigned with `userId = ndb.StringProperty()` using Google App Engine.

Comment: "works for me" - I could not reproduce your problem. What Python version are you using? Is there any chance your userId is a other than a built-in unicode object (assuming you are on Python2.x), and not some class with a custom `__unicode__`  method?

Comment: @jsbueno It's possible - I am working with Google App Engine and userId is assigned as follows: userId = ndb.StringProperty(), however when I called type(userId) it said <type 'unicode'>

Answer (score 2):

Once you mentioned Google App Engine I played with an example using it:

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import quoteattr
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext.ndb.model import Model


class Foo(Model):
    bar=ndb.StringProperty()


foo=Foo(bar='''barç"á<&'  >


''')

print type(foo.bar)

print quoteattr(foo.bar)
```

The problem here is that foo.bar is an str, so you are going to have the encoding problem. Thera two ways of solving it:

1) Using u prefix. So

```
foo=Foo(bar='''barç"á<&'  >


    ''')
```

Becomes

```
foo=Foo(bar=u'''barç"á<&'  >


    ''')
```

2) Adding the two lines on the beginning of your scripts:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
```

I prefer the second approach. I configure Pycharm to add this lines on every new created py file.

Note that this problem only occurred when setting model property with a literal. Webapp2 and most of frameworks used o GAE converts request data to unicode so you don't have to bother about encoding/decoding.